# Any evidence in Qur'an of a word of Allah to Muhammad (pbuh) out of Qur'an?

Tags: quran, prophet-muhammad, allah

Is there any evidence in Qur'an that there was a word from Allah to Muhammad(pbuh) that is not included in Qur'an? I couldn't find an evidence. Also as Qur'an includes even Prophet's private life issues I doubt that there were an important issue for Muslims from Allah that is not included in Qur'an.

- Please just answer from Qur'an (while the question clearly asks so).
- Please don't give plain translation and include Arabic text.

Comment: Have you ever heard of "hadith qudsi"? Statements of Allah in the words of the Prophet.

Comment: @ashes999 Yes I know hadith qudsi that mainly collected by Hurr Al-Amili in 11th Islamic century but I seek for evidences in Qur'an. Unfortunately I have not received a convincing answer yet.

Answer (score 7):

These are a couple verses from the Quran:

> وَأَنزَلَ اللَّهُ عَلَيْكَ الْكِتَابَ وَالْحِكْمَةَ وَعَلَّمَكَ مَا
>   لَمْ تَكُن تَعْلَمُ
>
> And Allah has revealed to you the Book and Wisdom and has taught you
>   that which you did not know. [[4:113](http://quran.com/4/113)]

Hikmah (Wisdom) here is distinct from the Book (which is referring to Quran), so it is revelation besides the Quran.

> وَاذْكُرُوا نِعْمَتَ اللَّهِ عَلَيْكُمْ وَمَا أَنزَلَ عَلَيْكُم مِّنَ
>   الْكِتَابِ وَالْحِكْمَةِ يَعِظُكُم بِهِ
>
> And remember the favor of Allah upon you and what has been revealed to
>   you of the Book and wisdom by which He instructs you. [[2:231](http://quran.com/2/231)]

There are at least 10 examples (too long to list here) of revelation besides Qur'an. Scroll down to "Two Kinds of Revelation" in the book [Authority of Sunnah](http://ccm-inc.org/oldsite/iqra/articles/authsun/chap1.html) by Mufti Taqi Usmani for more detailed examples.

As for this verse:

> وَمَا يَنطِقُ عَنِ الْهَوَىٰ إِنْ هُوَ إِلَّا وَحْيٌ يُوحَىٰ
>
> Nor does he speak from [his own] inclination. It is not but a
>   revelation revealed, [[53:3-4](http://quran.com/53/3-4)]

The correct understanding is that whatever the Prophet says concerning the religion, is from ultimately from Allah, whether it was revealed in the Quran, or revealed to him separately. It is not "his opinion" as some claim, it is authoritative.

Another indirect proof is:

> وَأَطِيعُوا اللَّهَ وَأَطِيعُوا الرَّسُولَ وَاحْذَرُوا
>
> And obey Allah and obey the Messenger and beware [[5:92](http://quran.com/5/92)]

It wouldn't make sense to command us to obey the Messenger if that is exactly the same as obeying Allah alone. That would be redundant. It only makes sense if the Messenger has revelation from Allah besides the Quran, that there would be this distinction.

Answer (score 0):

What do you think about the holy prophet's ascent (Mi'raj)? It is only cited in Quran but of course Allah has talked with his messenger during such a mysterious journey, or at least has sent His Angels to bring messages from Him to His prophet! It is almost obvious. It was not like Allah sending an angel to His holy prophet for the angel to take the prophet --peace be upon him-- with himself and show him around, the universe. It was not a discovering journey. If you could accept this then see we are told every single praying is an ascent for the believers: الصلوة معراج المؤمن

Quran as it states is a book for guidance, it is to guide all the humanity up to the Day, all the guidance in one single volume book not so that not every saying of Allah would find a place in the guidance book. Also nowhere it is claimed to be a collection of all messages from Allah to his prophet, but always ,it is stated to be a guidance book, that's all.

The Muqatta'aat phrases in the beginning of some specific Surah are highly encrypted that even the Angel who was the messenger of Allah to His prophet wa not aware of its meaning, but the prophet knew their meanings, so that he should have given the key and the key is not in Quran otherwise the angel should have known about it as well. Allah knows best, though.

@Ahmadi's answer is perhaps the most direct and explicit answer to your question from Quran itself. There are verses in Quran clarifying that the holy prophet --peace be upon him-- was too much submitted to Allah

> قُلْ إِنَّ صَلَاتِي وَنُسُكِي وَمَحْيَايَ وَمَمَاتِي لِلَّـهِ رَبِّ
>   الْعَالَمِينَ / لَا شَرِيكَ لَهُ ۖ وَبِذَٰلِكَ أُمِرْتُ وَأَنَا
>   أَوَّلُ الْمُسْلِمِينَ
>
> Say: "Truly, my prayer and my service of sacrifice, my life and my
>   death, are (all) for Allah, the Cherisher of the Worlds: No partner
>   hath He / this am I commanded, and I am the first of those who bow to
>   His will. [6:162,163]

Explained further in Hadeeth that nothing he said or did unless it was what Allah has expected from him, his will coinciding to the will of Allah in this universe, so that whatever that he says is a saying of Allah, but in His prophet's language.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. 
Quran says:

> Your companion [Muhammad] has not strayed, nor has he erred, (2) Nor
>   does he speak from [his own] inclination. (3) It is not but a
>   revelation revealed, (4)

http://tanzil.net/#trans/en.sahih/53:3

This verse says anything prophet says is not from himself and is revelation from God.

But please note there are many un-authentic hadith said to be from prophet that prophet not said them really and were fabricated in the name of prophet during history for different reasons like political reasons.

According to above verses, every single word of prophet is from God.

Comment: This Ayah is about Qur'an itself not everything that Prophet (pbuh) has said.

Comment: **<comments removed>** Please try not to use comments like a chat room or discussion forum. If you find yourself veering away from *improving* the original post, it's time to bring it to the chat room. Thanks.